# What is the exponentiation of free quantum mechanical Hamiltonian?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H_0=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\Delta$ where $\hbar$ and $m$ are just some positive constants and $\Delta$ is the $n-$dimensional Laplacian.

Then, I encountered the following formula presented without any explanation.
\begin{equation}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}tH_0}f(x)=\Bigr(2\pi i \frac{\hbar}{m}t \Bigr)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i m \frac{(x-y)^2}{2\hbar t}} f(y) dy
\end{equation}

where $f(x)$ is a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t >0$.

Could anyone please explain why it is so? I know that $H_0$ is (essentially) self-adjoint so its exponentiation is a unitary operator. But I cannot make any meaning of this formula.

Comment: İt follows from this i believe. $e^{itH_0}f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}e^{itp^2}\hat{f}(x)$

Comment: FYI: should be $\hbar$ squared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just expressing $\exp(-it\Delta) f $ (let me set $\hbar=1$ and $m=1/2$ for simplicity) as the solution of the Schrodinger equation $\partial_t u = -i\Delta u$, $u(\vec{x}, 0)=f(\vec{x})$,  which is given by the convolution of $f$ and the Fourier transform of $\exp\left(-it\vec{k}^2\right)$, *i.e.* $(4\pi i t)^{-n/2} \exp\left(-\vec{x}^2/4it\right)$.

Comment: Oh....Thank you for your insight.